# How to fix the 'FileSystemException: An async operation is currently pending'?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I wrote a torrent download demo , look like this:

```dart
var peers....

for(var i =0;i < length;i++){
   var peer = peers[i];
   peer.start((List<int> data){
      _downloadFile.write(begin,end,data);
   });
}
```

I mean that there are mutiple `peer` try to access the `_file`.

```dart
`_downloadFile` code looks like this:
   ....
   var _access = _file.open(mode:FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
   ...
   Future write(int begin,int end, List<int> block) async{
       ....
       await _access.setPosition(begin);
       await _access.writeFrom(block);
       ....
   }
```

And it will throw exception : `FileSystemException: An async operation is currently pending`
I think the reason is that different fork invoke `setPosition`, so I try to make each fork to wait the write operation over:

```dart
`_downloadFile` code look like this:
   ....
   var _access = _file.open(mode:FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
   var _lock;
   ...
   Future write(int begin,int end, List<int> block) async{
       if(_lock != null) await _lock;
       var c = Completer();
       _lock = c.future;
       ....
       await _access.setPosition(begin);
       await _access.writeFrom(block);
       c.complete();
       ....
   }
```

If I understand correctly, when `peer` recieves data , it will call `write` method , then it should wait the `_lock` completed, but I still get `FileSystemException`.

Now I have to use `Stream` , with its `pause` and `resume` method to avoid this exception.

Can someone tell me what's the problems with the last codes? why the `_lock` does not work? Does Dart have something like 'object lock'?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You have to await write finish to write begin next write operation

Comment: Maybe you need to reset _lock to null when your done? Anyway the [mutex package](https://pub.dev/packages/mutex) provides a very good locking mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably using the localStorage package and are running into this issue: https://github.com/lesnitsky/flutter_localstorage/issues/56#issuecomment-800651187

"The problem will occur If two operation write at the same time to the file stored in local storage, while the first operation has not finished to write. Because the package has no safety to avoid accessing the same storage in parallel, this case might occur and throw the error".

Because the maintainer somehow doesn't recognize the problem, I made a fork and applied the changes myself to fix this error. Feel free to use it in your project as well :-)

https://github.com/Ocell-io/flutter_localstorage